# Mock third party api while calling through postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, mocking

I have a controller class which expose a Get API and return person info:

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

@Autowired
PersonService personService;


@GetMapping
public Person getPersonInfo() {
    return personService.getPerson();
}
}
```

In personService I am connecting to a third party and get person info from this API. 
Now I want to call getPersonInfo() API in my controller using postman. How can I mock third party response in this senario?
I know this is possible if you uset  test(integration or unit) and wiremock.
How about using just postman to call my API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`@Profile` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-profiles).

```java
public interface PersonService {
...
}

@Service
@Profile("default")
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
...
}

@Service
@Profile("mock")
public class MockPersonService implements PersonService {
...
}
```

When defined above, you can select profile with `appliation.properties`. For example:

```
spring.profiles.active=mock
```